# Как перехватить исключение из вызываемой формы в вызывающем методе?

Tags: c#, winforms, исключения

Из некоторого метода вызывается форма, которая при создании создает исключение:

```
void CallExternalForm() {
    try {
        var f = new Form2();
        f.ShowDialog();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

...

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    throw new Exception("test");
}
```

В данном случае исключение не перехватывается, а создается Unhandled Exception.
Разумеется, эти исключения можно отловить в:

```
Application.ThreadException
```

или

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException
```

Но можно ли как-то заставить форму вернуть исключение в вызывающий метод?

Comment: Все понял, сначала не так понял. Вы же вызываете конструктор `Form2`, а не `Form2_Load`, а он вызывается в `InitializeComponent`. Вот Вы написали про `Application.ThreadException` и `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` - да так можно и нужно. В противном случае будет *An unhandled exception*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем примере — никак.

Событие `Load` отправляет не ваш код, а фреймворк WinForms асинхронно, не из конструктора. Обработчики событий **не должны** бросать исключений.

Вам придётся отлавливать исключения внутри `Form2_Load`.